# PhpMyAdmin connectiong from cpanel use custom user

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I connect trough  CPanel to PhpMyAdmin successfully but the user is the same that was used to login into CPanel.

How can I connect using a recently created database user that have the required credentials?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I have the same need but I am on a hosted site and they claim it's not possible to get cPanel to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can Create New Databases form your CPanel and You can also Create Database Users in Cpanel. You can create than one user and may be more than one databases.

After Creating User and Databse you have to go down(scroll down) the page where you can find User Assignment ( assign specific user to specific database )

Simple Select a User from drop down (ComboBox) and Select a Database to assign it .
 
Now Use Selected User's  credential to your Database Config file .
[image]

you don't need to use  these user's credential to login to phpmyadmin

Comment: I did that already but i want to login to phpmyadmin using that user. get it?

Comment: Yes it is possible 
Open "Xampp/PhpMyAdmin/index.php" file and 
change first Line of code with 
<?php header('Location:yourLoginPage.php'); ?>
Check Yours Login/Authantication from database "mysql" table "users" 
and Create some session varibles to to Remember User